# VBA Excel: General change detection

Tags: vba, excel

Is there an object and/or function that can detect or represent a general change on a worksheet? Something similar to (for example) `ComboBox1_Change()` but could be applied to a whole worksheet. Almost something like `Worksheet1_Change()`. Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: All Workbook, Worksheet change events: http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/event.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to use the worksheet change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "Change Detected!"
End Sub
```

There are instances will this will throw you in to an infinite loop.  Consider this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Range("A1").Value = "Change"

End Sub
```

Set a breakpoint on the Range("A1") code and make a change somewhere else on the sheet and count how many time that breakpoint gets hit.  When you get tired of hitting F5, stop the code and try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("A1").Value = "Change"

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

You'll see that the code only fires once.  Which is probably what you're after.

It's very important that you have the Application.EnableEvents = True line in there, or else you'll get the appearance that your code isn't working (by default EnableEvents does not revert back to True at the end of the code).

Comment: How often do you recommend acting on that kind of sub? I was thinking of having a graph/cell be updated with every change that occured. Would that slow things down you think?

Comment: Usually not often and you have to be careful that you don't send yourself in to an infinite loop (each change fires that event, so if you have a change to a cell that changes another cell, things start stacking up).

Comment: You can work around that issue with Application.EnableEvents = false at the start and Application.EnableEvents = true at the end.  I'll update my answer.